# Migration issue with SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

Earlier we had one of our database in SQL Server 2008 and last month we moved it to SQL Azure.

In the table, one of the column is set as Identity and auto increment is set. Also this column is a primary key and it is referenced as foreign key in many other tables.

[image: auto increment]

When our DB is in SQL Server 2008, this column values were incremented properly and there is no issue with the sequence of generated values.

After moving our DB to SQL Azure, there was sudden jump on the generated values as

1687
1688
1689
10001
10002
10003
.
.
20100
20101

On searching, I found that in SQL Server 2012 and SQL Azure "Identity Increment" is not guaranteed. Also SEQUENCE feature is not available in SQL Azure(refere: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/723601/support-native-sequences-in-sql-azure).

I tried to add a new column and remove the problematic one, but since it is a primary key and dependencies on other tables, I can't DROP this column.

This migrated DB is a business critical one. Please let me know the efficient way to overcome this issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import data then you should use identity insert when bulk loading the data to keep integrity.

If the problem is in the course of using the application you get large jumps, then that shouldn't be a problem, identity is a surrogate key and the values have no business use. If they do have business use then you have a database design issue and probably should use a different method of generating the values (ie key pool).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/ms176057.aspx

Try to Use DBCC CHECKIDENT to ressed your column:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT 
( 
table_name
  [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ]
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```